# what is django request handler callback()

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at the base handler for http requests in Django 1.4 (base.py, https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/handlers/base.py#L109).

After the code has cycled through the request middleware and the view middleware, you can see it checks one more time if `response is None` at line 107. Then it tries to run the `callback()` function (line 109). I would like to know where this method is defined. I'm looking at the stack trace for an error and after this method is called the next line in the trace is for a file that doesn't exist in my dev environment (where the error is not occurring). So, clearly, this `callback()` does something I'm not familiar with. Is this a configuration setting, python keyword, or something?

How does Django/python decide what to do when it reaches `callback()` at line 109?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callback` is the view from your `urls.py` that matches the url you are accessing.  Django gets this `callback` by calling [`resolver.resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) (in the Django 1.4 version of the file you linked to, this happens on [line 98](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/handlers/base.py#L98)).

In Python, functions are objects, so `resolver.resolve` can return a function that can be called later.